# Problemas para enviar informacion de un formulario hacia mysql o base de datos

Tags: php

Code=

```
<?php
$conectar = @mysqli_connect('localhost','root','');
//verificar conexion
if(!$conectar){
  echo 'No se puedo conectar con el servidor';
}else{
  $base = mysqli_select_db('lista');
  if(!$base){
    echo 'Nose encontro la base de datos';
  }
}

$nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
$admision = $_POST['admision'];
$grado = $_POST['curso'];
//hacemos la sentencia de sql
$sqli = "INSERT INTO primero VALUES('$nombre','$admision','curso')";
//ejecutamos la sentencia sql
$ejecutar = mysql_query($sqli);
if(!$ejecutar){
  echo "Hubo un error";
}else{
  echo "Datos guardados correctamente";
}
 ?>
```

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ''lista''
>   (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting ')' in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\prueba\conexion.php on line 8

Comment: Disculpe, ya lo he corregido.

Comment: Bienvenido a Stackoverflow. Las preguntas con títulos como *AŸUDA es urgente*, o títulos como el tuyo son mal recibidas en esta comunidad. Un ejemplo de título para tu caso sería: *¿Por qué esta consulta de inserción no funciona en PHP/MySQL?*  o algo así.

Comment: Cuando usas `mysqli_select_db` tienes que pasarle dos parámetros: la conexión y en el nombre la base de datos, por ejemplo: **`$base = mysqli_select_db($conectar,'lista');`** [Revisa la documentación](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.select-db.php). Aunque eso sólo sería útil para cambiar de base de datos, ya que la puedes seleccionar cuando creas la conexión directamente, ahorrándote así la llamada a `mysqli_select_db`. Por cierto, el uso de `@` en PHP es considerado una mala práctica. Silencia los errores y hace difícil la depuración.

Comment: Ok, gracias lo tendre en cuenta para ayudar o para preguntar. Tengo ese problema el cual todo en bd esta correcto y no me almacena ninguna informacion.

Comment: ¿Enviar formulario a phpmyadmin? no sabía que se podían enviar allá.

Comment: [Revisa los ejemplos del manual](https://secure.php.net/manual/es/function.mysqli-connect.php), verás que la bd se puede seleccionar al conectar: `$mysqli = mysqli_connect("localhost", "mi_usuario", "mi_contraseña", "mi_bd");

if (!$mysqli) {
    echo "Error: No se pudo conectar a MySQL." . PHP_EOL;
    echo "errno de depuración: " . mysqli_connect_errno() . PHP_EOL;
    echo "error de depuración: " . mysqli_connect_error() . PHP_EOL;
}else{ //usar la conexion}`  Debes cambiar los datos por tu usuario, contraseña y nombre de base de datos.

Comment: Quiero almacenar en la base de dato |Nombre del estudiante|Admision (es decir si lo admiten o no en la institucion) | Curso al cual va ingresar quiero que las listas que hice almacenen esa informacion ya que estan configuradas asi mismo como en el codigo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intenta este código, te dirá el error que haya ocurrido o bien insertará los datos correctamente.

Al conectar puedes pasar la bd como último parámetro a la función de conexión.

Había un error en el `INSERT` en alguna de tus variables.

Es bueno que controles el POST, aquí he usado ternarios para ello. Y es lo primero que debes hacer antes de crear la conexión.

```
<?php 
    $nombre   = ( !empty($_POST['nombre']) )   ? $_POST['nombre']   : NULL;
    $admision = ( !empty($_POST['admision']) ) ? $_POST['admision'] : NULL;
    $curso    = ( !empty($_POST['curso']) )    ? $_POST['curso']    : NULL;

    if ($nombre && $admision && $curso) {
        $mysqli = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "lista"); 
        if (!$mysqli) { 
            $msgOut= "Error: No se pudo conectar a MySQL." . mysqli_connect_error();
        } else {
            $sql = "INSERT INTO primero VALUES('$nombre','$admision','$curso')";
            $ejecutar = mysql_query($sql);
            if(!$ejecutar){
                $msgOut="Hubo un error".mysqli_error($mysqli);
            } else {
                $msgOut="Datos guardados correctamente";
            }
        }   
    } else {
        $msgOut="Hay datos vacíos en el POST";
    }
    echo $msgOut;
?>
```

Comment: Gracias por su comentario, trabajare con el codigo que usted me ha editado que esta trabajado a la perfeccion muchas gracias.

Comment: @D.Cabas de nada. Otra cosa, la inserción como la tienes es susceptible a ataques de inyección SQL. Convendría que leas sobre eso y sobre la forma de prevenirlo mediante consultas preparadas. Y en cuanto a la conexión con la API mysqli, recomendaría que aprendas el estilo orientado a objetos, por ser más claro e intuitivo. Lo dejo para que lo tengas en cuenta.

Comment: Muchas gracias Dios lo Bendiga.